# Laravel hasOne() Function Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-8

I have 2 models named AdminContent, AdminCategory. I have content_category_id in my admin_contents table. I have category_id and category_name in my admin_categories table. I linked category_id with content_category_id foreign.
I am using the hasOne() function in my Admin Content model. But I get the error Using $this when not in object context!
My main goal is to get content_category_id value from admin_categories table name column

**Migrations**

```
// Admin Categories Migration
Schema::create( 'admin_categories', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('ctgry_id')->unique();
            $table->string('category_name', 50)->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```
// Admin Contents Migration
Schema::create('admin_contents', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('cntnt_id')->unique();
            $table->string('content_title');
            $table->text('content_content');
            $table->string('content_slug');

            $table->bigInteger('content_category_id');
            $table->foreign('content_category_id')->references('ctgry_id')->on('admin_categories');
            
            $table->string('content_status');
            $table->string('create_user');
            $table->string('content_tags');
            $table->string('content_excerpt');
            $table->dateTime('posted_at');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Models**

```
// AdminContent Model
protected $table = "admin_contents";

    protected $fillable = [
        'content_title', 'content_content',
        'content_category_id', 'content_status', 'create_user','content_tags',
        'content_excerpt',
        'created_at', 'updated_at'
    ];

    protected $guards = [
        'cntnt_id',
    ];

    public function setCategoryName()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(AdminCategory::class);
    }
```

When I want to access with $this->hasOne(AdminCategory::class) I get this error!

Answer (score 0):

First: relationships in Laravel are based in standardize models, using `'id'` as column name for ids. If you are using another name for firstKey, you should add it to relationship definition, as stated in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#main-content). I mean, your relationship should not work because Eloquent doesn't know which are your tables first keys.

Second: when you define a relationship you should call id from your model. So how are you accessing to `$this->hasOne(AdminCategory::class)`?
It should be something like `AdminContent::with('setCategoryName')`

Maybe showing some code from your controller we can give you a more accurate reply.

Answer (score 0):

What I want is this,
I get the blog content with query and print it. But I am printing the content_category_id value as the id value in category table. What I need to do is get the content_category_id and the id value in the category table, the category name linked to that id. Thanks in advance for your help.

**Admin Content Model**

```php
namespace App\Models\Admin;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AdminContent extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "admin_contents";

    protected $primaryKey = 'cntnt_id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'content_title', 'content_content',
        'content_category_id', 'content_status', 'create_user','content_tags',
        'content_excerpt',
        'created_at', 'updated_at'
    ];

    protected $guards = [
        'cntnt_id',
    ];

    public function _all()
    {
        return self::all();
    }

    public static function setCategoryName()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(AdminCategory::class, 'content_category_id', 'ctgry_id');
    }
}
```

**Admin Category Model**

```php
namespace App\Models\Admin;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AdminCategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'admin_categories';

    protected $primaryKey = 'ctgry_id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'category_name', 'updated_at'
    ];

    protected $quards = [
        'ctgry_id', 'created_at'
    ];

}
```

**Post Controller**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\Admin\AdminContent;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('frontend.blog');
    }

    public function getCategoryName()
    {
        return AdminContent::find(1)->setCategoryName;
    }
}
```

**MySQL Tables**

https://www.hizliresim.com/2z0337a